# How do you intercept a bean reference?

Tags: spring, spring-bean

My Spring configuration looks like

```
    ...
    <bean id="myWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        ...
        <property name="sql" value="%[insert.sql.command]" />
 ==>    <property name="dataSource" ref="outDataSource1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        ...
        <property name="sql" value="%[insert.sql.command]" />
 ==>    <property name="dataSource" ref="outDataSource2" />
    </bean>
    ...
    <bean id="outDataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="%[outds1.driverClassName]" />
        <property name="url" value="%[outds1.url]" />
        <property name="username" value="%[outds1.username]" />
        <property name="password" value="%[outds1.password]" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="outDataSource2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="%[outds2.driverClassName]" />
        <property name="url" value="%[outds2.url]" />
        <property name="username" value="%[outds2.username]" />
        <property name="password" value="%[outds2.password]" />
    </bean>
    ...
```

I would like to display information for the `DataSource` referenced in each *writer* (`JdbcBatchItemWriter` class). `DataSource` is implemented by a Spring `DriverManagerDataSource`.

For example, display infos :

```
(DriverManagerDataSource).getUrl()
(DriverManagerDataSource).getUsername()
```

So I wrapped `JdbcBatchItemWriter` in a, say `JdbcBatchItemWriterWrapper`, based on an `ApplicationContextAware`.

Since `JdbcBatchItemWriter` DOES NOT HAVE any `getDataSource()` getter, I need to resolve/instantiate the `ref` of the property `dataSource` programatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place you could intercept the `DataSource` is before the [`setDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html#setDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-) call implied by the

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="outDataSource2" />
```

One solution is to extend the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` and override its `setDataSource`, log the value that is passed to it, then delegate to the `super` implementation.

Instead of providing `JdbcBatchItemWriter` as the bean class, you provide your subclass.

Comment: Thx a lot, Sotirios, :-)
(I should have switch to this solution earlier without requesting help... i didn't drink enough coffee yesterday)